# Can I calculate NDVI with openCV C++ from an image captured from camera with IR filter

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image captured by the camera with IR filter, I want to get NDVI index from that image with openCV, but I don't know how to do it, can somebody help me?
I know the function NDVI = (NIR-R)/(NIR+R) but I can't figured out how to get NIR values from that image.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a Python script:

```
#assuming we have image named frame
b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)
numerator = cv2.addWeighted(b, 1, r, 1, 0)
denominator = cv2.addWeighted(b, 1, r, -1, 0)
ndvi = cv2.divide(numerator, denominator)
```

This script creates monochromatic ndvi image.

I bet you might do something similiar in C++